# POST Result Select not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using javascript to post an array to a PHP file and the result is put into a div. The result from the php is a set of radio buttons, however when I try to use javascript to select them it does not work. 
Note: the post function works perfectly fine.

Javascript Post (first file)

```
   $.post('newUserTeams.php', { 'teams[]': teams },
    function(result) {
        $('#tab3').html(result);
    });
```

PHP echo (second file)

```
echo("<label class='radio'>");
    echo("<input type='radio' name='team".$teams[$i]."' id='hi'>");
    echo("<i></i>Full Privilege User</label>");
echo("<label class='radio'>");
    echo("<input type='radio' name='team".$teams[$i]."'>");
    echo("<i></i>Limited Access User</label>");
```

Javascript Select Radio buttons (first file)

```
 $("#hi").change(function(){
     alert($(this).val());
 });
```

Comment: `$("#hi").on( "change", function() {` ..

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are wiring a "change" event handler to an element "#hi", when the element is not yet ready. For this, you have use the "on" method to bind the event handler.

So, in your first file, edit your code to:

```
$(document).on('change', '#hi', function () {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because after you ajax the 'HTML' from php, you should add the change event in post callback.

so your post function should change into this:

```
$.post('newUserTeams.php', { 'teams[]': teams },
function(result) {
     $('#tab3').html(result);
     $("#hi").on('change', function(){
         alert($(this).val());
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where are you calling this function, but it could be due to when page document ready executes it is not done. What you need to do is add the method change after it is created:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "objects.php",
    }).done(function( data ) {
        $('#tab3').html(data);
        $('#hi').on('change', function()
        {
            alert($(this).val());
        }
        );
    });
});
```